# Concave Object With High Edges

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I am new to Blender (I made a donut!).
Anyway, I am having a tough time getting this floor mat design right and would appreciate some advice.
The object has concave edges which I can't seem to replicate.
I have tried many different methods but can seem to get it right (see pictures).[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can begin with the outer shape of your mat:

[image]

Press <kbd>i</kbd> to inset:

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

Extrude up the border:

[image]

Or you can begin with the inner shape of your mat:

[image]

Extrude it up:

[image]

Select the side edges and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*:

[image]

Just after this extrude, enable the *Offset Even* option in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Extrude up the border:

[image]